# MiniZinc decision variable non contiguous range

Tags: variables, range, minizinc

what is the best way of defining the range  of an array decision  variable when it is not a contiguous sequence of integers apart from writing too many constraints?

An example:
enum PRODUCTS ={product_1,product_2,product_3,product_4};

array [PRODUCTS] of var 0..2         : x; // contiguous
array [PRODUCTS] of var 0,3,10        : y; ///non contiguous sequence and error

i tried also with the
set of int

such as 
set of int : y_range= 0,1,3;

enum PRODUCTS ={product_1,product_2,product_3,product_4};

array [PRODUCTS] of var 0..2         : x; // contiguous
array [PRODUCTS] of var y_range        : y; ///non contiguous sequence and error

but didn't work out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-continuous domains are allowed in MiniZinc. It seems you just made a mistake in your syntax. The following code works:

```
enum PRODUCTS ={product_1,product_2,product_3,product_4};
array [PRODUCTS] of var {0,3,10} : y;
```

Note that a non-continuous set literal, which initializes the domains of your variables, needs curly brackets (`{}`).